# Can we say that the integral over a circle of a combination of analytic functions is $0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose we have a function $f(z)$ that is analytic only when $Im(z)\leq 0$. Then we know that $g(z) = \overline{f(\bar{z})}$ is analytic where $Im(z)\geq 0$. If we define $h(z) = f(z)$ when $Im(z)\leq 0$ and $h(z) = g(z)$ when $Im(z)>0$ then is the integral of $h$ over any closed loop around the origin equal to $0$? I Think this is true since the way we define $h$, it is analytic everywhere on and inside the circle, but it seems a bit strange so I would like to clarify it.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a hint: there is some trickiness that lies in what happens at $Im(z)=0$. To illustrate this, we can break up the circle in the following way:

Let $C$ denote the circle. Then let $C_1$ denote the upper half circle, and $C_2$ denote the lower half circle, where $C_1$ and $C_2$ both run along the line $Re(z)=0$. Hence, $C=C_1+C_2$, so the following equality holds:

$$\int_Ch(z)=\int_{C_1}h(z) + \int_{C_2}h(z)$$

Since $h(z)=f(z)$ is analytic interior to and on the curve $C_2$, it's integral vanishes there, so we have

$$\int_Ch(z)=\int_{C_1}h(z)$$

However, $h(z)$ has different definitions on this domain, depending on if $Im(z)=0$ or not. Hence, your question is asking if $h(z)$ is continuous as $z$ moves from the $Im(z)=0$ axis toward the interior of the half-circle. Try to prove whether or not this is true!

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure, but it seems like $h$ is continuous?

Comment: But I'm not quite sure how to show it...

Comment: To Dman: If $f(z)=iz$ for Im$(z)\leq  0$ then when $a,b$ are real with $b<0$ we have  $h(a+ib)=f(a+ib)=ia-b$  but $g(a-ib)=\overline {i(a+ib}=$ $\overline {ia-b}=-ia-b.$ So if $a\ne 0$ is fixed and $b\to 0^-$,  the function $h$ is discontinuous at $a.$

Comment: so my statement is not true?